# Liferay 6.2 custom joins columns with same names are overlapping

Tags: java, sql, inner-join, liferay-6

I have created a custom join following this [tutorial](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/06/liferay-custom-sql-on-multiple-tables.html), two of the tables contain some columns with the same name and in the result set the value of the first table column are overriding the values of second table.

Comment: Do you expect us to go through the same tutorial before being able to answer your question? Please provide a [mcve] _in this question_ (to make it independent of external resources that might go away, and be indexable). Also, please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

SQL aliases are used to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name.

```
SELECT 
  table1.comlumn1 AS table1Column1,
  table2.comlumn1 AS table2Column1
FROM 
  tab1 AS table1
  JOIN tab2 AS table2
    ON table1.id =  table2.table1Id
```